# Dynamically change address in the URL bar

Tags: ajax, url, browser-history

Okay, I have seem similar questions around Stack sites, yet some of them were asked as far back as four years ago, so given the recent developments in HTML, jQuery and PHP, I'm convinced there are new workarounds.

Suppose I have a domain *www.mysite.co.uk*, which has an ajax that, once triggered, clears the default on-load content #0, and replaces it with content #1.

(This content can also be accessed by going to *www.mysite.co.uk/1*)

Then a user may trigger another ajax that will clear content #1 and populate with content #2.

This is where I have a problem. Because clicking the Back button will not send the user back to content #1 (in fact if there is no history, the Back button is greyed out).

What I want to do, is when user triggers an ajax that populates the page with content #3, I also want it to change the URL bar to *www.mysite.co.uk/3*, so this way the same content will load when the page is refreshed, instead of going back to the default content #0.

Hope this makes sense.

I know that www.asana.com do it, but not sure how.

I'm already developing grey hair by trying to sort this out.

Edit: I've seen some examples where they do that by #anchoring, or with a ?get_variable, but  I'd rather do it by changing the URL-proper, like Asana.com does it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for JavaScript's `pushState()` method in the history API:

[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Note: you can check compatibility with browsers on [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)